# how can I get more information from dbus?

Tags: d-bus

I try to figure what methods and data I can access using `DBus`, using the following command,

```
dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=net.connman /net/connman org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

I got,

```
method return time=1569225134.223103 sender=:1.5 -> destination=:1.77 serial=121 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node>
  <node name="service"/>
  <node name="technology"/>
</node>
"
```

I know there is "stuff" inside service and technology, I have found some by trial and error, some other by looking on internet. But how can I figure what is inside those nodes ?
My goal is to figure everything that I can access for `ConnMan` using `DBus`, so a more generalist question would be, how to explore everything related to `ConnMan` methods/data I can access with `DBus`?

thx!